# Fossil: Deleting missing files in one command?

Tags: dvcs, fossil

Is there a way to delete "MISSING" files explicitly without having to delete them with `fossil rm` one by one?

I've recently created a repository with a Flash XFL folder in it and Flash seems to delete and create some binary files somewhat arbitrarily. Having to delete them manually every time I commit is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nevermind. I'm an idiot. Fossil has me covered with `fossil addremove`. Seems like this will replace `fossil add .` in my workflow now.

It really *does* include everything but the kitchen sink. Thanks, drh.

Comment: If it is any consolation: I also had this problem - luckily for me though - somebody got there first - and provided the answer. This is also going into my workflow going forward! ;-)